# How to transform a csv file from wide form to long form in Python

Tags: python, csv, row, export-to-csv

imagine the following situation:

```
Name    Links       Blabla

name1   a b c       x

name2   d e f g h   y
```

As you can see, the link field has several strings split by a space. What I'm trying to obtain is:

```
Name    Links       Blabla

name1   a           x
name1   b           x
name1   c           x
name2   d           y
name2   e           y
name2   f           y
name2   g           y
name2   h           y
```

I have no clue why it's not working. This is what I have so far:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open(mySourceFile), delimiter = myDelimiter)
#..Code for opening Writer etc..
mySourceFileHeaders = reader.fieldnames
myExtraRows = row["Links"].split()
for line in reader:
   for counter in myExtrarows:
     writer.writerow(line)
```

And I'm a bit stuck here. I'll keep on searching (not for a heart of gold) but meanwhile: any help is appreciated!

Comment: `code`

writer = csv.DictWriter(open(myTargetFile, "w+"), myIncludeColumns, extrasaction='ignore')
            writer.writeheader()
            for line in reader:
                columnToSplit=line['links'].split()
                print "line = ", line
                print "columnToSplit = ", columnToSplit
                for eachlink in columnToSplit:
                    print "eachlink = ", eachlink
                    writer.writerow({'links': each link})

`code`

So the only think I need to add, is in the last line: I there need the values of the first and last column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the standard conversion of a data table from wide to long format (hence my proposed edit to your question's title).

I'm not sure what DictReader is gaining you here, but you need to use nested loops to deal with this

```
with open(inputfile) as f1, open(outputfile,"w") as f2:
    r=csv.DictReader(f1)
    w = csv.writer(f2)
    w.writerow(r.fieldnames)

    for d in r:
        links=d['Links'].split()
        for l in links:
            w.writerow([d['Name'], l, d['Blabla']])
```

The outer loop iterates through the input file. The inner loop then writes out one line per entry in the Links field of the current input line.

The use of `with` ensures the input and output files are closed when you are done.

Given the following input

```
Name,Links,Blabla
name1,"a b c","x"
name2,"d e f g h","y"
```

this produces an output file like this

```
Name,Links,Blabla
name1,a,x
name1,b,x
name1,c,x
name2,d,y
name2,e,y
name2,f,y
name2,g,y
name2,h,y
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. Your result gives me a syntax error, I look further into it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would read each row from the original file and write
the desired format to a new csv.

To get the 2nd column of links separated out, the conditional should be
something like:

```
for row in csv_rows:
    if len(row[1].split()) > 1:
        for link in row[1].split():
            new_csvfile.write(','.join(row[0], row[1].split()[link])
    else:
        new_csvfile.write(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this:

```
        writer = csv.DictWriter(open(myTargetFile, "w+"), myIncludeColumns, extrasaction='ignore')
        writer.writeheader()
        for line in reader:
            columnToSplit=line['links'].split()
            print "line = ", line
            print "columnToSplit = ", columnToSplit
            for eachlink in columnToSplit:
                print "eachlink = ", eachlink
                line['link']=eachlink
                writer.writerow(line)
```

Edit: it still doesn't work, I must be overlooking something. Now I have this:

```
        for line in reader:
            links=line[myColumnToSplit].split()
            for linkcounter in links:
                writer.writerow(line)
```

Although the value of the link counter is correct, it still writes the original (not splittet) line. It just repeats the number of lines written to the amount of split values. So if it has to split 4 values, it simply writes that line 4 times, but with the whole string, not the one that is split.